# How to store and retrieve the mp3 file from sqlite database?

Tags: android, sqlite, audio, mp3

I am developing android apps for a child. I have to use more than 500 mp3 file. Can you give me a brief idea of how to store and retrieve the mp3 files from sqlite ?

If you have any other ideas, please share.

Answer (score 2):

You **DONT** store MP3s into a database. You store the link to the MP3s in the database **BIG** difference.

Try this link http://www.screaming-penguin.com/node/7742

Comment: thanx bro, can you give me some example or link so that i can implement it on my apps.

Comment: **but if that app is distributed to another user, how he will be able to use those mp3's?**

Answer (score 0):

Store mp3 file in local path(that is in sdcard or in phone memory) and store that local path in Database.When you want to play that mp3 file take local url from database and go to the local url path and play the mp3 file.

Comment: **but if that app is distributed to another user, how he will be able to use those mp3's?**

Answer (score 0):

My problem is also somewhat similar to you...
[check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9425887/storing-patt-file-in-sqlite-database)

**If I store local path of the file into database, how I'll be able to access the file when I run the app on another device????**