# Storing *.patt file in Sqlite Database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, design-patterns

I have a `.patt` (pattern) file which I want to store in `Sqlite Database` and retrieve it later in order to match it with another pattern.

**contents of pattern file(*.patt)**

```
 178 176 175 176 173 172 173 173 169 167 167 169 169 164 166 167
 178 176 176 174 174 173 172 174 171 169 168 171 167 168 166 168
 175 171 171 165 166 164 163 161 160 162 157 160 165 168 167 168
 172 172 145 102 102  99 103  99  96  96  96 106 159 170 168 167
 175 172 144  96  93  90  89  88  86  87  86 101 157 167 166 168
```

and so on....

I don't know to what extent `Sqlite` support this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can just define the field as a BLOB, and put and get it as a string. No problem whatsoever.

Comment: In my app, I'll have some predefined patterns that I want to store in database. When a user uses the app, pattern matching should happen based on pattern created dynamically by user and the one present in database. I wont edit the file once it's in database. I just want to store in once and retrieve multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `blob` data-type for such operations. 
However, It would be bad habit to store & retrieve a file in Sqlite. It may effect in performance of application for operation reading/writing file data into sqlite. You should store it directly as file and store its path inside the sqlite database. This way it will be easy to retrieve.

Comment: In my app, I'll have some predefined patterns that I want to store in database. When a user uses the app, pattern matching should happen based on pattern created dynamically by user and the one present in database. **I wont edit the file once it's in database. I just want to store in once and retrieve multiple times.**

Comment: that you can google it. but still my suggest is to store file's path when you are retrieving it multiple times.

Comment: Like this : `CREATE TABLE Gallery(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, pattern BLOB)`  and  `insert into Gallery(pattern) values('D:\Data\pattern.patt')` ???... But then how to retrieve and use it?

Comment: no no i said bolb is for storing file, but in your case you need a String type column name filePath varchar(50); now store the above path you mentioned in your comment

Comment: but if I store only the **PATH of the file** in the database and then run application on some other phone, how it will work without the source files as they are present on local machine?